# Reverse data of grid in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I have a 3*2 grid (3 columns, 2 rows) with text on each box.
[image]

I need to reverse the position of the text in order to have `1, 1` at the top-left and `3, 2` at the bottom-right (because `3, 2` means third column, second row).

I created this [grid](https://jsfiddle.net/i5ar/pmjhp3qo/) fiddle.

I tried both `reverse()` and `sort()` but none of them works.
Is there a way to reverse the order of the generated groups?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you don't need to sort data in this case. Just set correct position of cells and text according to `row` and `cell` values. I've changed your fiddle a little - added `cellWidth` and `cellHeight` and fixed positioning of cells and text in them.

```js
let data = {
  "cols": 3,
  "rows": 2,
  "rect_set": [{
    "col": 3,
    "row": 2,
  }, {
    "col": 3,
    "row": 1,
  }, {
    "col": 2,
    "row": 2,
  }, {
    "col": 2,
    "row": 1,
  }, {
    "col": 1,
    "row": 2,
  }, {
    "col": 1,
    "row": 1,
  }, ]
};

let width = 256;
let height = 64;
let cellWidth = width / data.cols;
let cellHeight = height / data.rows;

let svg = d3.select('#grid')
  .append('svg').attr('width', width).attr('height', height);

let cols = data.cols;
let rows = data.rows;

let group = svg.selectAll('g').data(data.rect_set.sort((a,b)=>{
 if (a.col < b.col) return 1;
  return -1;
}))
  .enter()
  .append('g');

group.append('rect')
  .attr('x', function(d) {return cellWidth * (d.col - 1);})
  .attr('y', function(d) {return cellHeight * (d.row - 1);})
  .attr('width', width / cols)
  .attr('height', 32)
  .attr('stroke-width', 4);

// TODO: Reverse.
group.append('text')
  .attr('x', function(d) {return cellWidth * (d.col - 1) + 16;})
  .attr('y', function(d) {return cellHeight * (d.row - 1) + 16;})
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return `${d.col}, ${d.row}`;
  });
```

```css
rect {
  fill: white;
  stroke: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
```